# Can't push my files in SPCK Editor going to my Github Repository. What can i do to troubleshoot this Push Rejected Error?

Tags: github

Can't push my files in SPCK Editor going to my Github Repository. What can i do to troubleshoot this Push Rejected Error??

[this was the error appearing in my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzMWK.jpg)

Comment: Okay, problem solved. You have to clone first the repository and make changes inside it before you commit and push in SPCK Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved. You have to clone the repository first and make changes inside it before you commit and push in SPCK Editor.